# Python - is `threading.Event` "set" during garbage collection?

Tags: python, multithreading, events, garbage-collection

The title of this post pretty much sums up my question - will threads waiting on an `Event` be notified if that event has been garbage collected? In my particular case I have a class whose instances have an `Event` as an attribute, and I'm wondering whether I should implement a `__del__` method on this class that calls `self.event.set()` before it's garbage collected.

I'm new to asynchronicity, so if event's don't `set()` when they're garbage collected, perhaps it's bad practice to do so, and better to let threads hang? Thanks in advance for any responses.

Comment: Can you concoct a test for your issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that it's not necessarily the case that waiting for an `Event` implies the `Event` isn't in trash.  *Cyclic* trash is one possibility, and here's another:

```
import threading

class C(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.e = threading.Event()

    def __del__(self):
        print("going away")

def f():
    C().e.wait()

t = threading.Thread(target=f)
t.start()
print("main ending")
```

That prints:

```
going away
main ending
```

and then it hangs forever, as Python attempts to `.join()` the thread as part of interpreter shutdown processing.

The function `f()`, run in a thread, creates an instance of `C` that becomes trash immediately after its `e` attribute is retrieved.  So its `__del__` method is called, and "going away" is displayed.

You can infer from the behavior that, no, a trash `Event` does *not* get set by magic.  But it's not going to come up in practice, so don't worry about it ;-)

Comment: I'm implementing a promise system similar to [this](https://github.com/xogeny/aplus). Each promise holds an event, and whenever a promise is resolved, its associated event is `set()`. My main concern was that there might be cases where unresolved promises get dropped from memory. It seems like having the safety net there (or perhaps an error?) is reasonable.

Comment: Note that I lied a bit, to answer the question you _meant_ to ask ;-)  That is, in my sample the `Event` isn't really trash, because the `e.wait` part of `C().e.wait()` creates a bound method object that holds a reference to the `Event`, and that's reachable from the thread.  In what you're doing, it seems you supply your own `wait()` methods, and accessing those will similarly create bound method objects that will keep _your_ objects technically alive (not trash).  I can't answer whether you want to `set` your objects by magic, beyond noting that magic is rarely helpful in asynch contexts.

Answer (score 2):

Since other objects hold a reference to the event, the event itself won't be deleted or garbage collected. It has no idea that your object is being deleted. Whether you want your class to have a `__del__` that sets the event when the object is deleted (either naturally through having its ref count go to zero or though garbage collection) is entirely dependent on your event system design. Suppose I have a dozen objects referencing the event. Do I want the event fired when each one goes away? Depends!

Comment: Duh! I didn't really think about the fact that if a thread was waiting on an event it would have to have a reference to it, preventing it from being garbage collected.

However, I'm pretty sure the `set()` method just sets a flag to `True`, so even if 12 objects tried to `set`, it would only notify once (unless it was reset each time)?

Comment: You could get anywhere from 12 to 1 event triggers depending on how fast the waiting thread services the event and what it does with the event. If you want the waiting thread to terminate when all objects holding the event are deleted... that can be kinda hard because you'd have to keep track of the number of such objects. (unless you only have 1 such object... then that counting is easy!).

Comment: In my case, the event isn't a public attribute of the object, so it should really only be `set` by that specific object. The only public action is to `wait`. Ultimately I'm implementing a promise system similar to [this](https://github.com/xogeny/aplus).